# What is difference between load_path & auto load_path in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, load-path

What is difference between load path & auto load path? if i have added any dir to auto-load path then should i need to require that file in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant `autoload_paths` :

From documentation:

> config.autoload_paths accepts an array of additional paths to prepend to the load path. By default, all app, lib, vendor and mock paths are included in this list.

[Source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration)